# Why pool does not run all threads together?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

It seems that `Pool.map` does not run all processes in parallel. I am not sure, but it looks like it runs them by bunches of 5-10 threads. I tried `maxtaskperchild` argument too, but seems the same. I am not sure, is it true (or am I confusing something)? Why? Is it a way to run all of them them with `Pool.map()` in parallel? If no, sure no problem to write such a function, but I was surprised.

```py
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(50, maxtasksperchild=50)
res = pool.map(f, fargs)
```

Comment: Most likely you don't have 50 CPUs to assign your processes to, therefore they run in batches, according to your OS scheduler.

Comment: if `f` is IO bound then you should see them all being run together.  `maxtasksperchild` doesn't control that, it just restarts processes when they've executed that number of tasks (e.g. useful in the case of memory leaks)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7 under Linux does run everything at the same time, see for example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def fn(i):
    print(f"enter {i}")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(f"exit {i}")

with multiprocessing.Pool(50) as pool:
    pool.map(fn, range(50))
```

results in 50 `enter` lines being printed, then 50 `exit` lines being printed

in my comment I shouldn't have said "IO bound" but "non-CPU bound" or even "short lived" as I get nice deterministic results until I reduce the sleep below 10ms or so

Comment: and I expected the same... strange, OK, may be it's my local problem